# Dojo: Mixing Calendar Views in 1.7

Tags: javascript, calendar, widget, dojo

world!

I'm trying to create a date picker widget that shows the years first, then the month, then the date. From the example I found online (http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojox/widget/Calendar.html), it appears that it's possible. I just need to know how it should be done to be compatible with AMD? I tried things like:

define(['dojo/_base/declare', 'dojox/widget/_CalendarBase', 'dojox/widget/_CalendarDay', 'dojox/widget/_CalendarYear'], function(declare, calendarBase, calendarDay, calendarYear){
    declare('lt.CustomSerialCalendar', [calendarBase, calendarDay, calendarYear], {});
});

But nothing I've tried seems to work.  I tried putting `dojox/widget/Calendar` in the dependencies list, and I got a `dojo not defined` error.  How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, it seems that I've found the answer to my question.  The calendar classes are outdated, and aren't compatible with AMD loading.  Therefore I had to take `async: true` out of my `<script>` tag loading Dojo.